Measure how far Order $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]$ differs from $\mathcal{O}_K$
Let $K:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{b})/\Bbb Q$ (with $n \ge 2$) a numer field extension gouverned by irreducible polynomial $X^n-b$. Then in general it's a picant question if the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K$ equals $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]$.
We surely know that $d:=[\mathcal{O}_K:\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]]$ is finite from lattice theory - or more generally theory of fin. gen. modules over PID's.
Initial Question: Is there any relation algebraic between $d$ and discriminant of polynomial $X^n -b$. More precisely, does the former always divide the latter? If yes, how to see it?
#UPDATE: Previously there was a meanwhile deleted answer posted that the reation is given by $\mathrm{Disc}(X^n -b)= \mathrm{Disc}(\mathcal{O}_K) \cdot [\mathcal{O}_K:\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]]^2$. Could somebody sketch the idea how to prove it?
We know, since $\mathcal{O}_K$ admits an integral basis, we can express powers of $\sqrt[n]{b}$ as $\Bbb Z$- linear combinations of of the integral basis members, so $\mathrm{Disc}(X^n -b)$ differs from $\mathrm{Disc}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ by an integral square, precisely by square of determinant of integral base change matrix. But why does this equals $[\mathcal{O}_K:\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]]$?
Metaquestion: Are there "standard" techniques phrased in terms of invariants (beyound the "boring" invariant $d$) which "measure" how far $\mathcal{O}_K$ differs from $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]$.
$d$ lies of course as such measuring invariant "on the nose", but practically I would say it difficult to compute. So the hope is that there are "easier computable invariants" invariants which detect the discrepance between $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]$ by beeing - maybe in nontrivial way - related with $d$ and so providing indirect informations about $d$ itself. What I mean by this more precisely is in spirit of original question:
Eg, discriminant of $X^n-b$ is easy to compute. If answer to first question is positive and it is $\pm 1$, we win.
Of, course, one could ask more generally for arbitrary finite extensions $K/ \Bbb Q$ if there are "standard" techniques with nice computability properties to "measure the failure" how far $\mathcal{O}_K$ is from "shape" $\Bbb Z[r]$, for some $r \in \mathcal{O}_K$.
In other worts, how far the principal generator theorem holding for finite separable extensions - esp. ext' ns of number fields - fails when passing to their rings of integers.

You ask if the index $[\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]]$ divides ${\rm disc}(x^n - b)$, which is $\pm n^nb^{n-1}$. Sure, it always does and that divisibility has nothing special to do with the rings being $\mathbf Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]$.
When $K = \mathbf Q(\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ an algebraic integer having minimal polynomial $f(x)$,
$$
{\rm disc}(f) = [\mathcal O_K : \mathbf Z[\alpha]]^2{\rm disc}(\mathcal O_K),
$$
so in particular $[\mathcal O_K : \mathbf Z[\alpha]]^2 \mid {\rm disc}(f)$. That divisibility relation comes up early in almost any algebraic number theory textbook, since it's one of the quick ways to compute a ring of integers in simple cases: if ${\rm disc}(f)$ is squarefree then the divisibility shows $[\mathcal O_K : \mathbf Z[\alpha]] = 1$ and thus $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z[\alpha]$.
Necessary and sufficient conditions that $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[n]{b})$ has ring of integers $\mathbf Z[\sqrt[n]{b}]$, when $x^n - b$ is irreducible, $n \geq 2$, and $b \not= -1$, are here.
In order to determine prime factors of an index $[\mathcal O_K:\mathbf Z[\alpha]]$, you can use a theorem of Dedekind here.
One indirect way to see some ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ doesn't have the form $\mathbf Z[r]$ is that the different ideal of $K$ is non-principal: see Theorem 4.3 here and look at footnote 6 for a nice characterization of exactly when the different ideal of a number field is principal.
The standard way to measure the difference between any ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$ and an order inside it is using the conductor ideal of the order: see here.

Thanks! Do you maybe know if it is something known about the "defect measuring" between $\mathcal O_K $ and $\mathbf Z[\alpha]$ in more general situation where $K (=\Bbb Q(\beta)$ as separable by principal elt thm) is arbitrary number field; compare with last paragraph of the question? Or is it broad and we can only say something for specific cases like \mathbf $Q(\sqrt[n]{b})$?

@user267839 I added some other comments to my answer: look at the different ideal of $K$ and especially the conductor ideal of each order in $K$.

Is there any connection between the conductor ideals of orders to different ideal or discriminant ideal. The upshot seems to be: The precise control on how far an order differs from $O_K$ is governed by conductor ideals. On the other hand the different ideal - whose "primary" task is govern the ramification behavior - gives via non-principalness an indirect sufficent criterion for $O_K$ not having form $\Bbb Z[b]$. But that's not a neccessary criterion, so it looks that on one hand whensame the conductor ideal's  "raison d'etre" is to detect this discrepancy

between $O_K$ and $\Bbb Z[b]$, the different ideal "knows something" about this discrepancy "accidentally" as its main task is to govern ramification information. This raises the question about "deeper" connection between conductor ideals of orders and the different ideal. The only very very indirect connection familar to me is that of conductor-discriminant formula. As on one hand, discriminant has an immediate connection to different ideal as it's image under norm map, to connection between Artin conductors appearing in c-d formula and conductors of

of orders appear - if there is some - quite mysterios. So, motivated by this criterion for $O_K$ beeing of form $\Bbb Z[b]$ in terms of different ideal and "raison d'etre" of conductor ideals of orders to measure this discrepancy, this raises the question if there is a deeper connection between different ideal (resp discriminant ideal) and conductor ideals? Do you maybe know if there some profound interplay between there objects exists?
